# NameError: name 'Entry' is not defined Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
app = tk.Tk()
app.title("Text Editor")
def d(event):
    b = Entry(app, height=event.height, width=event.width)
app.bind('<Configure>', d)
app.mainloop()
```

It returns:

```
File "pythonapp.py", line 7, in d
    b = Entry(app, height=event.height, width=event.width)
NameError: name 'Entry' is not defined
```

Comment: `b = tk.Entry(...)`

Comment: Or bad way of doing is to import all modules from tkinter - `from tkinter import *`

Comment: @bigcounty ~ Why explain the bad way of doing it. You could have explained the other good way to do it. You can simply import only the widgets you need `from tkinter import Label, Button, Frame` and then use those names without prepending the namespace to them. It just may not be clear where they came from if the program gets very large. You **may** also have a conflict if some other module uses those names. Both of those possibilities are rare to none, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you import like this: `import tkinter as tk`, you need to prepend every widget instance with the `tk` namespace.

ex: `tk.Button()`, `tk.Entry()`, etc...